# Bass-guitar online exercises for not-beginner

Tags: technique, learning, bass-guitar, electric-bass-guitar, improvisation

I'm an intermediate bass guitarist, and I want to improve my left arm fingers work, and improvisation during bass solo.

I think I should learn not only by simply remember some tabs by famous bass guitarists, but from some excersises.

Comment: In general we discourage "Are there any X?" questions. A better question would be "What exercises can I do as an intermediate bass guitarist to improve [somethings]" or even better "How can I improve [somethings]? I'm an intermediate bass guitarist." Give us something to go on.

Comment: Updated the question. Sorry for bad quality question.

Comment: No worries, just hopefully you'll get better answers this way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I advise you to watch video school John Patitucci "Electric Bass". John shows a lot of exercises for the left and right hands.
You can find it here http://www.kat.ph/john-patitucci-electric-bass-2-video-pdf-t2949084.html

Also, I recommend you a series of lessons Jamey Aebersold "Play-A-Long". This will help you understand improvisation. 
http://extratorrent.com/torrent/246065/Aebersold+Jazz+Play-A-Long+Vol.++1+to+Vol.++106.html

Comment: May be, you have any links?

Comment: I added some links.

Answer (score 6):

Check out Scott's Bass Lessons https://www.scottsbasslessons.com/.

He creates educational videos for all abilities. Most of his videos are free but he also has a paid for area with access to more resources.

Answer (score 5):

I have created as site that has a ton of stuff - arpeggio exercises, transcriptions, a thing called the Pentatonic Lick Factory and lots of other bass guitar related things. There are plenty of things that will challenge even an experienced player.

http://bassoridiculoso.blogspot.com

Answer (score 1):

I play guitar, not bass, but I can answer for the effectiveness of a set of daily exercises for both technique (strength, speed, accuracy) and musical knowledge.

The exercises I use are those in David Mead's book "10 Minute Guitar Workout", but I'm sure others are available.  The exercises work to educate your ear as well as your fingers.

Unfortunately, I don't know of a bass version, or an online version.